# Synchronisation between mobile database and server database

Tags: android, ios, database, mobile-application, synchronization

**Description:**

This is for synchronising database of server to the mobile application, which has offline storage.
Database is changed only through server and all the clients should set their data accordingly.

**Requirement:**

If new data is added to the server  insert operation should be performed in client database as well with new data.
If data is updated in server , data with particular id should be updated in the client database as well.
if data is deleted in the server,  that data should be deleted from the local database as well.

**Structure of table to be synchronised...**

There is **last_date** field and **post_status** in every table in server database. The client has only **last_date** field in the table.

Whenever admin updates existing dataset **last_date** changes **post_id** remains same.

**post_status** is on and off if admin deletes the post from the database it will be in off status otherwise it will be in on status.

**Process:**

1. When client database is being synchronised for the first time all the dataset from the server database is downloaded sequentially.
2. When offline application has to synchronise, it request server to send it the data only after latest last_date. For example: with a get request to **API:** getdata.php?timestamp=1234.

Task for client after receiving server response:

server response will be like this for example: in JSON format:

```
[
{
  " post_id":"10", 
   "data":"Dummy Data",
   post_status: ON,
   last_modified:123124123
},
{
  " post_id":"11", 
   "data":"Dummy Data2",
   post_status: OFF,
   last_modified:5465465654
},
{
  " post_id":"4", 
   "data":"Dummy Data4",
   post_status: ON,
   last_modified:5465465654
}
]
```

**Let's suppose:**

**1st Dictionary item :** To be inserted.

**2nd dictionary item:** To be deleted.

**3rd dictionary item:** represents modification of preexisting post.

**Now I want to know what is the best synchronisation algorithm that best suites this requirement**

**Questions:**

1. How should the client know about the updated item? Checking if each post_id returned from server already exist in local database? For example if there is 1000 datas added to the server after the timestamp sent by user to the server, the client should compare if each id exists in local database and if id is found in local database update that dataset with new data supplied by the server.
2. What if admin deletes the row directly from the database without setting its status to OFF?